# Unique list of days which overlapping from the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

This is my MySQL table:

```
ID    start       end
====  =====       ===
01    01/01/2020  10/01/2020
02    09/01/2020  31/01/2020
03    02/01/2020  04/01/2020
```

I'm trying to get unique list of days which overlapping with themself, so this is a expected result:

```
results
=====
02/01/2020
03/01/2020
04/01/2020
09/01/2020
10/01/2020
```

I tried to get this using "between", but it only returns a date range. This is my query:

```
SELECT t1.* 
  FROM $table AS t1, $table AS t2 
 WHERE t1.id > t2.id 
   AND (t1.check_in_date BETWEEN t2.check_in_date AND t2.check_in_date 
    OR  t1.check_out_date BETWEEN t2.check_in_date AND t2.check_out_date 
    OR  t1.check_in_date >= t2.check_in_date AND t1.check_out_date <= t2.check_out_date)
```

Can I  expand this query to achive my goal or need I to find completly diffrent way?

**UPDATE (copied from the comment)**

> I'm using MariaDB v.10.0.44

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS ( SELECT MIN(`start`) `date`
         FROM sourcetable
       UNION ALL
         SELECT `date` + INTERVAL 1 DAY
         FROM cte
         WHERE `date` < ( SELECT MAX(`end`)
                          FROM sourcetable )
       )
SELECT cte.`date`
FROM cte
JOIN sourcetable src ON cte.`date` BETWEEN src.`start` AND src.`end`
GROUP BY cte.`date`
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

[fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kwhVVXxsYXr13CYhe2VdUw/0)

In MySQL 5.x you may use the next technique:

```
SELECT cte.`date`
FROM ( SELECT min_date.min_start + INTERVAL n1.n*10+n2.n DAY `date`
       FROM ( SELECT MIN(sourcetable.`start`) min_start
              FROM sourcetable ) min_date,
            ( SELECT 0 n UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION  SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 
              UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION  SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 ) n1,
            ( SELECT 0 n UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION  SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 
              UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION  SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 ) n2
     ) cte
JOIN sourcetable src ON cte.`date` BETWEEN src.`start` AND src.`end`
GROUP BY cte.`date`
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

[fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kwhVVXxsYXr13CYhe2VdUw/2)

Above query assumes that the difference between minimal and maximal date in a table is not more than 99 days. If it may be greater then more digits-generated subqueries must be added with proper expression edition.

Comment: Sorry but I don't precised. Im using mariadb in v10.0.44 so I can't use cte. Anyway, your solution is correct, so very thanks for your time - I really appreciate it. Can anyone tell me how to convert this query to work with my version of the database?

Comment: @KamilŚwiątek Does some limitation of possible dates range length (i.e. MAX(end) - MIN(start) in days) exists?

Comment: Yes, I wanna to limitate of possible dates range using two cases.

1. The query should not check for entries where the end date is less than TODAY ()

2. For returned data, I would like to display only results that have today or a future date

Comment: @KamilŚwiątek I mean that in your version you must generate dynamic table with the numbers from zero to max amount of days between the least and the grreatest date in the period in interest. If this amount is large then the query may be complex and slow. I'll show a pattern...

Comment: I spend a lot of time to make this query works and you did it just in moment. Very thanks! Now I will able to custom this to my needs.